# Replace all part of string after a character

Tags: c#

I have a string that looks like this:

```
string myString = "This looks like 100,02 while others don't";
myString  = myString.Replace("", ""); //How do I replace it?
```

Now I would like to replace my string empty after ",0". So the final string should look like:

```
"This looks like 100,0"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Using `.Split`? Or perhaps `.Substring`? Or maybe with a regex? What has your research shown for possible solutions? Why haven't any of those worked for you?

Comment: Well so far I have seen that you can replace part of the string which is why I used .Replace(). I am not sure how to remove all the characters after a particular char.

Comment: `myString  = myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf(",0") + 2);`

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure about your desired output but try this, maybe you will achieve it.

```
String  = String.Substring(0, String.IndexOf(",0") + 2);
```